# Where do I need to create HDFS users?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have to create an account for an application who needs to store data on HDFS.
I understood that for creating a user on HDFS (I'm using HDP 2.3), I have to execute these commands:

```
useradd -G *groupname* *username*
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/*username*
hdfs dfs -chown *username*:*groupname* /user/*username*
```

My question is:
I understood that when I create a folder on HDFS this is not replicated on all the cluster, only the data are spread on all the data nodes.
Have I to execute these commands on EVERY node (namenode+datanode+edgenode) of the cluster or only on the node used by the application to access HDFS (in my case the edge node)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you might be knowing only metadata is stored on the Name node and data are stored on the Data node.

```
useradd -G <groupname> <username>
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/<username>
hdfs dfs -chown <username>:<groupname> /user/<username>
```

The above commands are part of metadata, so these information will be stored on the Name node. So you need to execute the above command on the edge node of your cluster and metadata generated from above command will be stored on the Name node.

Only when data storage will happen, then Data node will come into picture.

Conclusion: Just execute your above command only on the `edge node` of the cluster.

Comment: I usually have to use super user to do that: `sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/<username>`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a client want to store or process the data-stored on HDFS, NN will first check whether it has access to that. Based on the access level the data will acess by the user.

You doesnt have to run the above commands on every DN. Access will be check at the NN itself and based on the type of user, data will be accessible. You can run the commands on NN only and NN will take care after.